# Add a new line every 5 outputs

Tags: c

I have this code in which I need to find all prime numbers from 2 to 1000 and need to print them out in groups of 5 in each line. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, a, count;
    printf("Prime numbers between 2 and 1000 are : \n");
    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
            if (i % a == 0)
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 2)
            printf("%d\t", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One approach is to add all of your prime numbers to an array and then when you're done getting all the prime numbers, you can have another loop that print them out in groups of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new `counter` to count the number of prime numbers printed until the current loop. If this counter value is divisable by `5`, print a new line.

```
int main()
{
    int i,a,count;
    printf("Prime numbers between 2 and 1000 are : \n");

    int cnt_prime = 0;  // count the number of prime numbers until this loop

    for (i=2;i<1000;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        for (a=1;a<=i;a++)
        {
            if (i%a==0)
                count++;
        }
        if (count==2) {
            printf("%d\t", i);
            cnt_prime++;
            if (cnt_prime % 5 == 0)   // print new line after each five numbers
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is another faster approach to find the prime numbers in a range. You can read about **sieve of eratosthenes** from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/

Comment: Thank you this solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer, but you could add another counter-variable called `prime_count` and initialize it with value `0`. Then each time you print a prime, you increment that variable. After printing a prime you then check wether `prime_count` is equal to `4`. If that's the case you print a newline-character and reset `prime_counter` to `0`.
The code could look something like this:

```
int main()
{
 int i,a,count,prime_count=0;
 printf("Prime numbers between 2 and 1000 are : \n");
 for (i=2;i<1000;i++)
 {
     count=0;
         for (a=1;a<=i;a++)
         {
            if (i%a==0)
                count++;
         }
     if (count==2)
     {
         printf("%d\t",i);
         prime_count++;
         if (prime_count == 4)
         {
             printf("\n");
             prime_count = 0;
         }
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: For consistency, you should add a final statement `if (prime_count) printf("\n");` at the end of `main()`

Answer (score 0):

You can check till square root of N to verify prime no need to check till N it makes your code O(sqrt(n)) [refer this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) for more info about the algorithm.You can have a variable called printCounter to check total elements printed on console when it become a multiple of 5 we can print a new line.

```c
int main() {
    int i, a, printCount = 0 ;
    printf("Prime numbers between 2 and 1000 are : \n");
    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
        int isPrime = 1;
        for (a = 2; a * a <= i; a++) {
            if (i % a == 0){
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == 1) {
            printf("%d\t", i);
            printCount++;
        }
        if(printCount%5 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing braces after `if (i % a == 0)`... C is not Python

Comment: Also missing final newline at the end of `main()`: `if (printCount % 5 != 0) { printf("\n"); }`

Comment: Tq for correction @chqrlie